# WindowManager addView - Android 7.1.1

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I'm adding a small `TextView` at the bottom of my app when the app goes offline. So I have a `BroadcastReceiver` that monitors network connectivity changes and in the `onReceive`, I show the banner. Here is the banner class which adds the `TextView` on top of the existing view:

```
public static void show() {
        if (!isShowing && !isAppBackgrounded()) {
            MyApplication app = MyApplication.getInstance();
            WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) app.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Resources res = app.getResources();
            TextView offlineTv = app.getOfflineTv();

            if (offlineTv.getWindowToken() != null) {
                return;
            }

            offlineTv.setText("Offline");
            offlineTv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(app, R.color.yellow));
            offlineTv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            offlineTv.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(app, R.color.dark_grey));
            offlineTv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, app.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.offline_banner_text_size));

            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = createLayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST, null);
            windowManager.addView(offlineTv, params);
            isShowing = true;
        }
    }
```

Here is the `createLayoutParams` method

```
 private static WindowManager.LayoutParams createLayoutParams(int type, @Nullable IBinder windowToken) {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        layoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
        layoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        layoutParams.height = 25;
        layoutParams.gravity = GravityCompat.getAbsoluteGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM, ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
        layoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
        layoutParams.type = type;
        layoutParams.token = windowToken;
        layoutParams.windowAnimations = android.R.style.Animation_Toast;

        return layoutParams;
    }
```

This code works fine on all the devices but 7.1.1 devices. In 7.1.1 device, the `TextView` shows for a while and then disappears. There is just a blank white space instead of the `TextView` on 7.1.1 devices. Any idea why is it happening?

EDIT: as asked in the comment, here is how I get the TextView: This is MyApplication class extending Application:

```
TextView offlineTv = null;
/** Get the TextView to show the offline message */
    public TextView getOfflineTv() {
        if (offlineTv == null) {
            offlineTv = new TextView(this);
        }
        return offlineTv;
    }

    /** Clear the offline TextView once we are done showing it */
    public void clearOfflineTv() {
        if (offlineTv != null) {
            offlineTv = null;
        }
    }
```

And this is my BroadcastReceiver, where I show / hide it:

```
public class DSConnectionChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    /**
     * Connection-changed callback
     * @param context Context
     * @param intent Intent
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean connected = false;
        boolean isCellularData = false;

        if (activeNetworkInfo != null) {
            connected = activeNetworkInfo.isAvailable() && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
            int type = activeNetworkInfo.getType();
            isCellularData = (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) || (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_DUN);
        }

        if (connected) {
            if (OfflineBanner.isShowing()) {
                OfflineBanner.dismiss();
            }
        } else {
            OfflineBanner.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post getOfflineTv() body from MyApplication class? Also please tell us when you use show()  and how/when you remove your offlineTv from WindowManager.

Comment: @Raphau I did post more details as per your request

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by you adding the `android.R.style.Animation_Toast` windowAnimation. When the animation finishes on an actual Toast the whole toast would disappear. In this case your view is in the hierarchy so instead of disappearing, it becomes blank.

What you should do is leave `layoutParams.windowAnimations` off of the params and instead create and attach the view with the visibility set to `View.GONE` then animate the view onto the screen manually

Manually animating the view can be achieved with the following utility:

```
Animation animIn = AnimationUtils.makeInAnimation(context, true);
textView.setAnimation(animIn);
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
textView.animate();
```

**Snackbar Alternative:**

```
public final class ConnectionBar {

     private static boolean mIsConnected = true; //static to preserve state
     private static ConnectionReceiver mReceiver; //static to detect leaks
     private static SnackBar mSnack; 

     private ConnectionBar() { /* required */ )

     public static void prepare(Context ctx) {
         if (mReceiver != null) {
             Log.e(TAG, "WARNING previous ConnectionBar was leaked");
         }
         mReceiver = new ConnectionReceiver();
         ctx.registerBroadcastReceiver(mReceiver);
         if (!mIsConnected) { //static so will remember from last screen
             showBar(ctx);
         }
     } 

     private static void showBar(Context ctx) {
         if (mSnack == null) {
             mSnack = Snackbar.make(view, message, SnackBar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
             mSnack.show();
         }
     }

     public static void release(Context ctx) {
         if (mReceiver != null) {
             ctx.unregisterBroadcastReceiver(mReceiver);
             mReceiver = null;
         }
         if (mSnack != null) {
             mSnack.dismiss();
         }
     }

     private static class ConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
             NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
             boolean isCellularData = false; //migrate this how you want
             if (activeNetworkInfo != null) {
                 ConnectionBar.mIsConnected = activeNetworkInfo.isAvailable() && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
                 int type = activeNetworkInfo.getType();
                 isCellularData = (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) || (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_DUN);
             }  
         }
         if (connected && ConnectionBar.mSnack != null) {
             ConnectionBar.mSnack.dismiss(); //check this, might need to wrap in runOnUiThread
         } else {
             ConnectionBar.showBar(context);
         }
    }
}
```

Then in your activity:

```
public void onResume() {
    ConnectionBar.prepare(this); //takes care of setting br too
}  

public void onPause() {
    ConnectionBar.release(this);
}
```

Comment: I tried what you did, it still disappears :( It happens only on 7.1.1 devices (not even 7.0 emulators)

Comment: How to do attach the text view? If you could, add that part  to the question. Can i ask why youre not just using an indefinite snackbar? (Do you need an  example? )

Comment: I added the part where I call `show()` to attach the TextView to the question. And sure, I'm not adding an indefinite SnackBar because I need to show it on all the screens when the app is offline. For me to do that, I'll have to add the SnackBar on all activities I have in the app. I don't have a BaseActivity :(

Comment: True, but tou could make a wrapper class that knows when a snackbar should be shown with a static method that gets called onresume in each screen (it might be less work than debugging this, plus snackbar is designed for this) I'll add an example

Answer (score 2):

If you want View in WindowManager remains more than **BroadcastReciever Lifecycle** you need to do it inside a class extends of service. check out [this tutorial](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-floating-camera-t3116108)

I think still there is problems with Lifecycle. How you use it and how the system handles it.
If you want to force system not to kill your service (and not to remove WindowManager) you have 3 options.

1. return OnStartCommand with the [proper flag](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT).

   return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
2. add foreground notification

   startForeground(123, NotificationFunction());
3. and If you have lots of processes to do add Accessibility Service. [check out this](https://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html)

Comment: thats a good point. I moved the code in a service, but it still keeps disappearing :(

Comment: Good. so it 's important now to know lifecycle of a service. System usually kill services when there is no process to keep it alive. but if you need to force system not to kill it there is three options to do. see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

This is an intented behaviour since Android 7.1 to prevent apps from using a toast view to overlay other apps indefinitely.  Whenever you use a `TYPE_TOAST` view, the system will impose a maximum of 3.5 seconds (i.e. that of a LONG toast) for the display of your view (and also change the view animation to the internal Toast style), after which your toast view will be hidden, **EXCEPT** where your app is the currently focused one.

To avoid crashing apps, your view still remains on the view hierarchy. In other words, you can still call `removeView` on it after it is hidden by the system, without causing an illegal state exception.

(Reference: See the commit message to the Android source: 
https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/aa07653d2eea38a7a5bda5944c8a353586916ae9 )

To display a view over other apps on Android 7.1 or above you may need to request the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission, prompt the user to get the Draw Over Apps permission, and use another view type, such as `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`.